# ¿Por qué mi lista enlazada duplica los valores de los nodos, cuando agrego más de un elemento?

Tags: c, punteros

No entiendo porque en la función **agregarDireccionesLinktree()** duplican todos los elementos insertados pero si comento la parte del else: si ya existe un elemento inicial inserte los siguientes al final como en un lista enlazada simple funciona correctamente pero no puedo agregar más elementos.

```
Esta es la funcion que simula una tabla hash con una lista enlazada para cada nodo de los nodos (ListaLinktree) aqui no hay error.

void crearLinktree() {
  printf("Ingrese el nombre del nuevo linktree: ");

  char nombreLinktree[10];
  scanf("%s[ˆ\n]", nombreLinktree);

  if (listaLinktree == NULL) {
    listaLinktree = (struct ListaLinktree*) malloc (sizeof(struct ListaLinktree));
    strncpy(listaLinktree->nombreInicio, nombreLinktree, 10);
    listaLinktree->abajo = NULL;
    agregarDireccionesLinktree(listaLinktree);
  } else {
    struct ListaLinktree* auxiliar = listaLinktree;

    while (auxiliar->abajo != NULL) {
      auxiliar = auxiliar->abajo;
    }
    auxiliar->abajo = (struct ListaLinktree*) malloc (sizeof(struct ListaLinktree));
    strncpy(auxiliar->abajo->nombreInicio, nombreLinktree, 10);
    auxiliar->abajo->abajo = NULL;
    agregarDireccionesLinktree(auxiliar->abajo);
  }
}
```

Esta es la funcion que rellena la lista enlazada asociada la nodo listaLinktree
el problema ocurre en el else cuando deseo agregar más de un elemento a la lista enlazada de nodos NodoLinktree

```
void agregarDireccionesLinktree(struct ListaLinktree* lista) {
  int indice;
  char opcion;

  while (opcion != 'n') {
    mostrarRegistro();

    printf("Ingrese el indice de la dirección que desea agregar a su linktree: ");
    scanf("%d[ˆ\n]", &indice);
    
    if (getRegistro(indice) == NULL) {
      printf("Indice invalido\n");
    } else {
      if (lista->siguiente == NULL) {
        lista->siguiente = (struct NodoLinktree*) malloc (sizeof(struct NodoLinktree));
        lista->siguiente->punteroNodoLista = getRegistro(indice);
        lista->siguiente->siguiente = NULL;
      } else {
        struct NodoLinktree* auxiliar = lista->siguiente;

        while (auxiliar->siguiente != NULL) {
          auxiliar = auxiliar->siguiente;
        }
        auxiliar->siguiente = (struct NodoLinktree*) malloc (sizeof(struct NodoLinktree));
        auxiliar->siguiente->punteroNodoLista = getRegistro(indice);
        auxiliar->siguiente->siguiente = NULL;
      }
    }
    system("clear");
    printf("\nDesea agregar más direcciones (y/n): ");
    scanf("%c[ˆ\n]", &opcion);
  }
}
```

Esta es la funcion que permite ver la lista asociada a un nodo listaLinktree determinado

```
void mostrarDireccionesAsociadas(struct ListaLinktree* listaLinktree) {
  if (listaLinktree->siguiente == NULL) {
    printf("Este linktr.ee no tiene direcciones asociadas\n");
  } else {
    struct NodoLinktree* auxiliar = listaLinktree->siguiente;
    do {
      printf("Alias: %s\n", auxiliar->punteroNodoLista->alias);
      printf("URL Acortado: %s\n", auxiliar->punteroNodoLista->URLAcortado);
      printf("URL Original: %s\n", auxiliar->punteroNodoLista->url);
      auxiliar = auxiliar->siguiente;
    } while (auxiliar != NULL);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hombre, te compartes `ListaLinktree` y mas o menos como la usas? Asi puedo probarlo en mi maquina.

Comment: Imaginate una lista enlazada que cada nodo sea una lista enlazada ok. La lista de las lista tiene como nombre de nodo ListaLinktree en agregarDirecciones mando la direccion del nodo donde deseo agregar la nueva lista

Comment: Mira, tu problema es de debug. Si quieres ayuda en el debug, no esperes que se lea el codigo y directamente podamos ver tu error. Tenemos que poder probarlo. Si no provees suficiente para poder probarlo, no podemos hacer nada